# Consulta SQL Not Exist

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Tengo dos tablas, con un campo en común, y lo que quiero es saber cuál elemento de la primera tabla NO tiene ninguna correspondencia con la segunda. He intentado usar not like, is not, pero siempre llego al mismo resultado equivocado. Por último, leí algo acerca de NOT EXIST, pero o no lo estoy haciendo bien, hay algo que no entiendo porque siempre me muestra error.

Alguien me puede ayudar?

- TABLA 1: orden_terapia

  > ->IdOrden  || IdTerapia
  >   ->1111     || 2020
  >   ->2325     || 2022
- TABLA 2: terapia_visita

  > ->IdTerapia || IdVisita
  >   ->2020      || 1515

El resultado que debería obtener sería el idOrden 2325. Espero haber sido claro con mi pregunta, gracias.

Mi logica es esta: Para que me muestre aquellas ordenes que SI tienen visitas

```
SELECT * from orden_terapia ot, terapia_visita tv WHERE ot.idTerapia = tv.idTerapia group by ot.idOrdenMed
```

Ahora bien, la consulta para que me muestre las que NO tienen visitas deberia ser la misma pero especificando que son los que no existen en la consulta anterior asi:

```
SELECT ot.idOrdenMed from orden_terapia ot WHERE NOT EXIST(SELECT * from orden_terapia ot, terapia_visita tv WHERE ot.idTerapia = tv.idTerapia group by ot.idOrdenMed)
```

Pero me da un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Bueno en la tabla 1, la llave foranea es idTerapia , en la tabla 2, la llave primaria es IdTerapia.

Comment: Gracias BetaM, pero ya logre encontrar una solucion, y no fue usando NOT EXIST. La solucion es mas simple de lo que pense: SELECT orden_terapia.idOrdenMed AS orden
                                    from orden_terapia left  join terapia_visita
                                    on orden_terapia.idTerapia = terapia_visita.idTerapia
                                    where terapia_visita.idVisita is NULL

Comment: asi es @Elkin esa justo era mi respuesta, procura para proximas preguntas siempre colocar el código desde el inicio

Comment: Pero me costo encontrarla!!. Gracia BetaM